# Generic Post Script driver for Windows Vista x64?

Tags: windows, drivers, printer

I have an old HP parallel port printer that is not supported by Vista. No drivers I've found online work with it.

As a last ditch effort, I was hoping to find some **generic postscript drivers** for Vista x64 in the hopes that the printer will accept those commands.

Does anyone know where I could come by such drivers?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the MS Publisher Imagesetter driver? It's included with Windows Vista under the Generic category if you manually install a printer.

Answer (score 2):

I normally use the Apple Postscript Printer driver. We use it for a Samba printer which generates PDF's.

Comment: That sounds good, but where can I find thaty driver?

Comment: It is a generic printer driver and comes standard. Normally it's under Apple.

Comment: go into your Add Printer wizard and select hardware from the list.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get the drivers to install on Vista if you share it from another PC say, running XP (assuming you have another PC).

Also, what sort of printer is it? You may be able to use the HP LaserJet 4 Driver, which is about as generic as I've seen HP drivers get.

Failing that, use the Apple Postscript Driver as suggested by Diago.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to this kind of problem is to use [Ghostscript](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/) as a raster image processor on the PC to drive the old printer. This depends on having a recent installation of Ghostscript, as well as [Redmon](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/redmon/index.htm) which is a generic tool that can make an ordinary application appear to be a printer port to Windows.

In addition to turning an old printer into a postscript compatible printer, Ghostscript can also produce high-quality PDF files, and with a suitable Redmon configuration can be used to make a print-to-PDF solution.

A trick I've found handy on occasion is to set it up to write TIFF or PNG files with Redmon to get a print-to-PNG printer.

Unfortunately, redmon isn't quite ready for 64-bit windows. According to its site, the authors are planning for a beta release that includes a 64-bit compatible build in June 2009, which if you are keeping score, is this month....

Google provided some hints that others are thinking about this issue, and there may be one or more 64-bit builds of redmon available from alternate sources.

Answer (score 0):

HP Universal Drivers will do the job

Answer (score 0):

This also works for Win7 (Windows 7), x64.

Install a driver for a printer that uses postscript. (It will usually have PS in the name. Almost any of these will work)

Use the print to file feature of the print driver, and specify the full path + extension when printing the file.

- Art Richards